# can't compile .so file since upgrading to mojave

Tags: python, gcc, compilation, cython, macos-mojave

I have a django application with a little bit of python.
Before upgrading to mojave, I compiled my cython file and everything worked.
Since Mojave I can't compile anymore or runserver.
I always have the same error :

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: dlopen(/project/algos/models.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/project/algos/models.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
/project/algos/models.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

I don't know where the problem comes from.

gcc -v

```
Configured with: -- prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

installation package:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

return with command xcode-select --install:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

MacOS version: 10.14.2
Xcode version: Version 10.1